# Run Oracle scheduler with error: ORA-20001: This procedure must be invoked from within an application session

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am building an interactive report with Oracle Apex. Currently, I created a trigger using `apex_mail` package to send an email whenever the table is updated. I also created a scheduler that run a procedure which update the table at daily basis. the procedure can be run successfully by itself, but when it runs in the job, the job failed, and detailed error is

```
ORA-20001: This procedure must be invoked from within an application session. 
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_MAIL", line 562 
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_MAIL", line 588 
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_MAIL", line 621 
ORA-06512: at "APEX_050000.WWV_FLOW_MAIL_API", line 47 
ORA-06512: at "USER.EMAIL_UPDATED", line 3 
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'USER.EMAIL_UPDATED' 
ORA-06512: at "USER.CHANGE_CURRENT_CONTACT", line 19 
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I can run the job successfully with the command as below only by setting use_current_session attribute to true.

```
 BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(
    JOB_NAME            => 'update_contact',
    USE_CURRENT_SESSION => TRUE);
 END;
```

I searched on the internet and find that it is something to do with the security issues. I tried to add the workspace id by using `select workspace_id from apex_applications where application_id = :p_app_id` and add a command `wwv_flow_api.set_security_group_id(workspace_id);`. But that doesn't work.

The following are my source code of sending emails.

```
 create or replace trigger email_updated
 after update on users_info
 for each row
 begin
 apex_mail.send(
    p_to       => 'Helen@oracle.com', 
    p_from     => 'Jason@oracle.com',
    p_body     => '',
    p_body_html     => '<b>Please</b> review the app for details');,
    p_subj     => 'Alert Email'); 
  end;
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I was also facing  same issue but it got resolved with
select workspace_id from apex_applications where application_id = :p_app_id 
and added a command wwv_flow_api.set_security_group_id(workspace_id); in same function and procedure/function before 
apex_mail.send() call. Hope this will help you.

Comment: This doesn't work for my procedure

Answer (score 0):

Setting security_group_id as @Amol sed, worked fine for me.
I have only a minor issue: i don't set p_from parameter so apex_mail.send have to use default value from configuration, instead the email received has FROM field the same as TO field.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using apex_mail to send mail, try using another procedure that is based on UTL_SMTP or UTL_MAIL. You can find examples here [(sending email from Oracle)](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql). The APEX_MAIL wont work from a scheduled job because the job runs in a seperate session.